# ORA-30036: unable to extend segment by 8 in undo tablespace 'UNDO'

Tags: sql, oracle, batch-file

I am trying to update the table which has millions of records.
However my update query will update around 2-3 millions of records.

I am facing below error on executing the update query.
I googled and found that I need to update the Table Space as DBA

But is there any work around for executing the update without actually extending the UNDO table space or something dba is not required

> > UPDATESERVICE SET CREATION_TIME = LAST_UPDATE_TIME WHERE CREATION_TIME is null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would expect that adding a rownum < 1000000 (or other number) and issuing commits between executions would workaround it, but you should size your undo tablespace appropriately.

Comment: can you tell me the command so that i can pass on to my DBA in sql

Comment: Sizing the undo appropriately is firstly a matter of working out what size of undo you need, based on your largest transactions. Here's the link to the 11.2 undo advisor documentation, which also has the syntax for changing the size. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10595/undo004.htm

Comment: @DavidAldridge That link seems to be broken - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24693_01/server.11203/e17120/undo004.htm works.